# How do I pass promise results around multiple functions?

Tags: javascript, promise

I've found lots of questions and answers about promises, but I can't quite wrap my head around how to apply them to my situation. I'm trying to use the result of a promise chain in another function using plain Javascript.

How would I go about doing something like the below?

My expected results is
Birthday Greeting
Happy birthday to you

Instead, I get
Birthday Greeting
[object Promise]

HTML

```
<div id="Heading">Birthday</div>
<p>
<div id="Paragraph"></div>
```

JS

```
//Create the phrase
function phrase() {
  let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
          resolve("Happy ");
      }, 3 * 100);
  });

  var q = 
    (p.then((result) => {
        return result + "birthday "
    }).then((result) => {
        return result + "to ";
    }).then((result) => {
        resolve( result + "you");
    })
  )
  
  return q;
}

//Add to the heading and return the phrase for use by another function
function func1() {
  document.getElementById("Heading").innerHTML += "Greeting";
  return phrase();
  
}

//Insert the phrase into the DOM
function func2() {
    document.getElementById("Paragraph").innerHTML = func1();
}
 
 
//Invoke the whole bit
func2();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 problems with your Promise

The first problem is

```
resolve(result + "you");
```

You don't return your final result after `Promise` resolved

The second problem is

```
[object Promise]
```

`Promise` object is just the state of waiting for results, but you didn't wait for any results, so that's why it's printed `[object Promise]`

I use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) for awaiting the final result from your `Promise`

```js
//Create the phrase
async function phrase() {
  let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("Happy ");
    }, 3 * 100);
  });

  //wait for final result with `async/await`
  var q =
    await (p.then((result) => {
      return result + "birthday "
    }).then((result) => {
      return result + "to ";
    }).then((result) => {
      //need to return final result after Promise resolved
      return result + "you";
    }))

  return q;
}

//Add to the heading and return the phrase for use by another function
async function func1() {
  document.getElementById("Heading").innerHTML += "Greeting";
  //wait for final result with `async/await`
  return await phrase();

}

//Insert the phrase into the DOM
async function func2() {
  //wait for final result with `async/await`
  document.getElementById("Paragraph").innerHTML = await func1();
}


//Invoke the whole bit
func2();
```

```html
<div id="Heading">Birthday</div>
  <div id="Paragraph"></div>
```

If you don't like `async/await` you can call `then` for awaiting results

```js
//Create the phrase
function phrase() {
  let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("Happy ");
    }, 3 * 100);
  });

  var q =
    (p.then((result) => {
      return result + "birthday "
    }).then((result) => {
      return result + "to ";
    }).then((result) => {
      return result + "you";
    }))

  return q;
}

//Add to the heading and return the phrase for use by another function
async function func1() {
  document.getElementById("Heading").innerHTML += "Greeting";
  return phrase();

}

//Insert the phrase into the DOM
async function func2() {
  func1().then(result => document.getElementById("Paragraph").innerHTML = result);
}


//Invoke the whole bit
func2();
```

```html
<div id="Heading">Birthday</div>
  <div id="Paragraph"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A promise is an object that represents a future value, *not the value itself*. To access the resolved value, you must use its `then()` method which accepts a callback function that will be invoked when the value available.

Since `func1()` returns `phrase()`'s promise, your `func2()` should look like this:

```
//Insert the phrase into the DOM
function func2() {
  func1().then(greeting => {
    document.getElementById("Paragraph").innerHTML = greeting;
  })
}
```

There also seems to be an error in your `phrase()` function. The last `then()` calls `resolve()` which doesn't exist. Here's `phrase()` rewritten for brevity:

```
function phrase() {
  let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve("Happy ")}, 3 * 100)
  })

  return p.then(result => result + "birthday ")
          .then(result => result + "to ")
          .then(result => result + "you")
}
```